# Visualizing ansi color escape codes in log files correctly in Emacs

Tags: emacs, colors, escape-characters

I have some log files that have ansi-color codes in them. When I open them in Emacs I see garbage:

[image]

As an example, I run the following:

```
ls --color=yes -ald -- * > my_files.txt
```

on a generic folder (using gnome-terminal in Ubuntu with zsh)

The interesting thing is that if I run

```
cat my_files.txt
```

the shell displays the contents correctly in color (i.e. the shell knows how to interpret those ansi-codes)

Is there any way to have Emacs display such files correctly as well?

Answer (score 17):

Use the emacs library `ansi-color.el`:

```
M-x load-library ansi-color
M-: (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
```